# Modifying email after button clicked in form getting error Object required

Tags: vba, outlook

In ThisOutlookSession:

```
Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
Set objMyNewMail = Inspector.CurrentItem
End Sub
```

In form code:

```
Private Sub SendButton_Click()
EmailFlagger.Hide
objMyNewMail.Body = objMyNewMail.Body & EmailFlagger.Exemptions.Text 
End Sub
```

I get the error Object required. How do I fix this?

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Where is `objMyNewMail` declared ?

Comment: The error is in the form code. objMyNewMail is declared at top of ThisOutlookSession Dim WithEvents objMyNewMail As MailItem

Comment: Which *exact line* though?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what line of code generates the error... Try to switch the lines of code in the Click event handler:

```
Private Sub SendButton_Click()
  objMyNewMail.Body = objMyNewMail.Body & EmailFlagger.Exemptions.Text
  EmailFlagger.Hide 
End Sub
```

The [NewInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841(v=office.15).aspx) event is not the right place for accessing the mail item object. Use the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869361(v=office.15).aspx) event instead. For example, in the NewInspector event handler you can subscribe to the Activate event where you can get the valid mail object.

Comment: The problem is with objMyNewMail

Comment: Use the Activate event of the Inspector class for accessing the mail item object instead.